# Child component not displaying on iOS

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to create a basic web app for desktop and mobile, but I've been running into a problem where using the root selector of my child component in my main component doesn't display the child component and makes the elements below it disappear.

Even if the html in the child component is blank, using the child-component selector still causes the problem, but if I remove the selector completely everything else looks fine.

Here is my code:

```css
.menu {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:620px) {
  .menu,
  .main,
  .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div style="overflow:auto">
  <div class="menu">
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <button>Test</button>
    <child-component></child-component>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the the child component (no CSS):

```
<p>Click the button</p>
<button [hidden]="started" (click)="start()">Start</button>
<button [hidden]="!started" (click)="stop()">Stop</button>
<button [hidden]="!canreset" (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
<p>Your message: {{display}}</p>
```

I looked at other posts and tried setting ViewEncapsulation.None on the child component, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Looks fine from the above code , https://codesandbox.io/s/2o8j9ypx5y

Comment: any console errors?